# Lexical analyzer with decimal numbers

Tags: java, regex, text-parsing, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a very basic text processor. the goal is to read from a file char by char and decide what type of token it is. basically what i have done is loaded all the chars into a queue and am using peek() and read() to check to see if the top element is (for this portion) a number, if it is append it to a string that will be used as a key in a hash map for different symbols.

by issue is in the following method. when the peek() sees a number that char gets passed to this method along with the queue for further processing. the problem i am having is that when i start building the number (as a string) i am using the java matches() with a regex to match only the numbers from 0-9, otherwise the method should stop building the string and return the lexeme object.

but that is where my problem is. for example after it reads the 4 and then 2 it keeps adding all the chars from the queue after until the it is empty--and lumping it all in under the number instead of creating new tokens.

any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm sort of stuck here.

my input:
    ABC := 42 ;
    EOF

the code:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param - cl ADT containing each character as read from a file
 * @param - c current head of the ADT
 * @return - lexeme 3 tuple that holds the keyword "number", the token read in, and the value 19
 */
public static Lexeme isNumber(CharQue<Character> cl, char c){
    Lexeme lexeme = new Lexeme();

    while (String.valueOf(c).matches("[0-9]") && (cl.hasNext())) {

        if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[0-9]")) {
            lexeme.buildKey(cl.read());

        } else if(c =='.'){
            lexeme.buildKey(c);
            c = cl.peek();
            break;
        }
    }

    while(String.valueOf(c).matches("[0-9]") && (cl.hasNext())){



        c = cl.read();
        if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[0-9]")) {
            lexeme.buildKey(c);
        }
    }

    lexeme.setTokken(lexeme.getKey());
    lexeme.setKey(NUMBER);

    return lexeme;
}
```

the results: in a 3 tuple of (keyword, what it read in, value assigned to that keyword).
    (keyword, token read, value)
    ------------------------
    (identifier, ABC, 28)
    (SPACE, , 26)
    (:=, , 24)
    (SPACE, , 26)
    (number, 42 ;EOF, 29)

desired output:
    (keyword, token, value)

---

```
(identifier, ABC, 28)
(SPACE, , 26)
(:=, , 24)
(SPACE, , 26)
(number, 42, 29)
( ;,  , 25)
(EOF, , 31)
```

Comment: Could you add what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Also, more information about what is in `cl` would be nice. Is the whole line supposed to be in it or are we just supposed to be analyzing one token?

Comment: You don't need a queue to be able to see the next character: that's overkill, and it's obscuring what you need to do, which is very simple: if the next char is a digit, accumulate it, and all the following chars that are also digits. If you stop at a dot, accumulate that too, and all the following digits. It's about six lines of code.

Comment: that's where this whole mess started. i was using a FileReader Object reading one char at a time, but i was always reading one character to many. i wanted a way to have a peek().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are exiting the first loop until you have exhausted all input. `c` is never updated (except in in the `else if`, which is never called). At the end of your program `c` is still equal to `'4'`.

As a general path to a solution, you should probably be checking if the value of `peek()` is an acceptable value. That way, if yes, you call `cl.read()`, if no, you have the end of your number.